# Get keys of object to form array of object failed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this object,

```
let obj = {
  "question_1": {
    answers: {
      "en": "How are you?",
      "cn": "ni hao ma"
    }
}}
```

I want to form an array of object like so `[{value: 'en'}, {value: 'cn'}]`

I tried this

```
const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((accum, [key, val], i) => {
  accum = [...accum, {value: Object.keys(val.answers)[i] }]
  return accum
}, [])
```

I only got `[{value: 'en'}]`, what's wrong with my reduce?

Comment: *"what's wrong with my reduce?"* You are literally reducing every object in `obj` to a single value of it's `answers` object. For outer every object, you are pulling out only the i-th answer: `{value: Object.keys(val.answers)[i] }`. It should rather be `return accum.concat(Object.keys(val.answers).map(k => ({value: k}));`. Note how this process every answer of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is using the index of the `reduce` function, that runs on the `Object.entities` result, not the internal `Object.keys`. A better way I believe is spreading the mapped array of the `Object.keys` like so:

```
const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((accum, [key, val], i) => {
  accum = [...accum, ...Object.keys(val.answers).map(value => ({ value }))]
  return accum
}, [])
```

This will give you what you want, but note that if more questions have the same answers keys you will get duplicates in the `result` array.

Comment: why you need to spread accum? can't it be just return `Object.keys(val.answers).map(lang => ({
    value: lang
  }))`

Comment: @Melissa94 so what is the point of the reduce function if you don't add up your results to the accum?

Comment: @Melissa94: You could do that, but then you have to use `.flatMap`: `const result = Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([_, val]) => Object.keys(val.answers).map(lang => ({ value: lang })));`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate and return all unique keys within each internal object too

```js
let obj = {
  "question_1": {
    answers: {
      "en": "How are you?",
      "cn": "ni hao ma"
    }
   },
   "question_2": {
        answers: {
          "en": "How are you?",
          "cn": "ni hao ma"
        }
    }
}

const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((accum, [key, val], i) => {
  Object.keys(val.answers).forEach(lang => {
      accum = {...accum, [lang]: {value: lang}}
  })
  
  return accum
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Comment: great, I used map

Comment: @Melissa94, you can make use of map if you do not want unique languages

Comment: this is my first time seeing this way, to eliminate duplication, I still don't understand the syntax though, `{...accum, [lang]: {value: lang}}` where can I read more about this? why [lang] doesn't compute and it become `{en: {value: en}}`?

Comment: @Melissa94, `...` is called spread syntax, and `[lang], { value, lang}` does become, `en: {value: en}`. and it will override any `en: {value: x}` that had previously been written

Comment: but the interation should be `{
    "value": "en"
  }` not `en: {value: x}`, where does the `en` in `en: {value: x}` gone to?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use reduce, you can just iterate over the keys, then push them in blocks into an array, spreading as you push:

```js
let obj = {
  "question_1": {
    answers: {
      "en": "How are you?",
      "cn": "ni hao ma"
    }
  },
  "question_2": {
    answers: {
      "fr": "Comment ca va"
    }
  }
}

const valueArray = []; /* array to push to */

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  valueArray.push(...Object.keys(obj[key].answers).map(value => {
    return {
      value
    }
  }));
});

console.log(valueArray)
```